# Why can a rubber sole undergo electrostatic discharge?

Tags: electrostatics, insulators

I understand that rubber soles can get gain (or get rid) of electrons when a person walks.How can electrons go from the soles to the fingers when that person touches an electric circuit connected to the ground?

If the soles are made of rubber, which is an insulator (resistance = 10^13 ohms), how can electrons reach the fingers? Why don't they just stay in the soles?